# переход по ссылке

Tags: javascript

```js
contents.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let target = e.target;
  if(target.tagName != 'A' ){
    return false
  }
   let targetA = confirm('Хотите покинуть страницу?');

  return targetA ? true : e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
  <fieldset id="contents">
    <legend>#contents</legend>
    <p>
      Как насчёт того, чтобы прочитать <a href="http://wikipedia.org">Википедию</a> или посетить <a href="http://w3.org"><i>W3.org</i></a> и узнать о современных стандартах?
    </p>
  </fieldset>
```

1. Сделайте так, чтобы при клике на ссылки внутри элемента id="contents" пользователю выводился вопрос о том, действительно ли он хочет покинуть страницу, и если он не хочет, то прерывать переход по ссылке.
2. У меня правильное решение ?!

Comment: Вы же видите, что нет.

Comment: @Igor почему ? клик по ссылке появляется вопрос и если ответ true то переход

Comment: @Igor догнал скрипт работает только на 1 ссылку так получается ?

Comment: Он у вас работает правильно, единственное, касательно 2 ссылки - вы там кликаете на <i>, отсюда и не правильно срабатывает

Comment: @InDevX спасибо за внимания я понял что тут приплыло всплытие :))

Comment: Интересно, а где такой код может пригодится?) Если можно просто добавить  ссылке `target="_blank"` и при клике пользователь и так не будет "покидать" страницу.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME  вот здесь  https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action#tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`e.target` — тот элемент, на который кликнули. В случае со второй ссылкой, клик происходит по элементу `<i></i>`, поэтому условие не срабатывает.

`e.target.closest('a')` — вместо 'a' может быть любой другой CSS-селектор. Если среди кликнутого элемента и всеми его родителями находится элемент, совпадающий с селектором - возвращается он, иначе - `null`.

```js
contents.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if ( e.target.closest('a') ) {
    let targetA = confirm('Хотите покинуть страницу?');
    return targetA ? true : e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

```html
<fieldset id="contents">
  <legend>#contents</legend>
  <p>
    Как насчёт того, чтобы прочитать <a href="http://wikipedia.org">Википедию</a> или посетить <a href="http://w3.org"><i>W3.org</i></a> и узнать о современных стандартах?
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Но этот код будет красивее с `onclick`, потому что `e.preventDefault()` — для addEventListener. А его аналог для onсобытий — `return false;` А confirm как-раз возвращает true или false)

```js
contents.onclick = function(e) {
  if ( e.target.closest('a') ) {
    return confirm('Хотите покинуть страницу?');
  }
}
```

```html
<fieldset id="contents">
  <legend>#contents</legend>
  <p>
    Как насчёт того, чтобы прочитать <a href="http://wikipedia.org">Википедию</a> или посетить <a href="http://w3.org"><i>W3.org</i></a> и узнать о современных стандартах?
  </p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: У Вас опечатка совадающий  исправьте пожалуйста для красоты

Comment: а так спасибо за развернутый ответ